# Fetching a jquery DYNAMIC value from website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, fetch

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

I'm getting the source code of the website but the value that I want to fetch is made dynamically via jQuery.

Let's assume that this is the source code of example.com

```
<div id="currentTime"></div>

<script>

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}

</script>
```

Yes, to get the source code is very easy but how do I fetch what's going on in between :

```
<div id="currentTime">{This is what I'm looking for}</div>
```

So... Iow... Fetching the value that have been made via javescript (or jQuery) in between the #currentTime div.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just an example... What if I need to fetch a newsletter that capture the string dynamically from a database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#result').load('otherPageUrl.php div#currentTime');
```

See: [Example](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

The only problem with this is cross domain restrictions or this will not be possible.  The other way you can do this is by the use of `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are solving this problem (i.e. loading the contents of another website). But, sure enough you can not do it using AJAX because of the [cross domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

One possible thing you can do is to, use an `iframe` in your page to load the website dynamically and then refer to the element you are interested in. By this way, you don't have to worry about the content that is dynamically generated in the other web page.

**Note:** Make sure you are not making use of any data from an external website that you are not supposed to grab this way. If at all it is a website you are not associated with, be sure to double check what you are doing is something you are allowed to do!